# Measuring Bioluminescent Algae Intensity

Tags: lab-techniques, bioluminescence

For a science project, I am required to measure the intensity of the light given off by the Algae, Pyrocystis lunula. Can a photometer with a range of 1-50000 lux be able to pick it up? If not, what are some tools to measure the intensity(without costing to much money.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27064806):

> The lunate cysts of Pyrocystis lunula have a bioluminescent emission spectrum with a peak intensity of 477.5 ± 1 nm.

So, almost any spectrophotometer should be able to detect it, it's just bluish visible light.

Comment: So even the cheap ones?

Comment: Even a phone camera